# How to avoid SQL RequestError: "The multi-part identifier ... could not be bound"?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am getting a SQL RequestError while trying to insert a string into a SQL Server table. The string is `com.redacted.redacted.redacted`. I think that the periods in the string are throwing some kind of red flag that it is a reference to some property of an object, or something along those lines. I am using the mssql node module for the request.

```
let myObj = {
    Date: '2015-06-22',
    PackageName: 'com.redacted.redacted.redacted'
}

let date = myObj['Date']
let pName = myObj['PackageName']

request.query('insert into myTable ([DATE],[PackageName]) values (' + date + ',' + pName + '))
```

I have not found anything online about trying to avoid using the dot notation, but I have found some of the opposite, trying to get into the notation. I also looked but there is no RegExp keyword to keep a period as literally a period.

The exact Error:

```
REQ ERROR
{ [RequestError: The multi-part identifier "com.redacted.redacted.redacted" could not be bound.]
    name: 'RequestError',
    message: 'The multi-part identifier "com.redacted.redacted.redacted" could not be bound.',
    code: 'EREQUEST',
    number: 4104,
    lineNumber: 1,
    state: 1,
    class: 16,
    serverName: 'REDACTED',
    procName: '' }
```

Comment: What is `request`? Post the *actual* error message returned.

Comment: You need to quote your strings in the SQL statement, you should use a prepared/parameterized insert to avoid this and prevent injection attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you use double quotes to wrap the sql

```
request.query("insert into myTable ([DATE],[PackageName]) values ('" + date + "','" + pName + "')")
```

Just to be safe, you may want replace any single quotes in pName with TWO single quotes